# pyinstaller No module named grpc

Tags: python, pyinstaller, grpc

My goal is to build an executable using pyinstaller. The python script I am trying to build imports grpc. The following is an example that illustrates the problem called hello.py.

```
  import grpc
  if __name__ == '__main__':
     print "hello world"
```

I do `pyinstaller hello.py` and that produces the expected dist directory. Then I run it like `./dist/hello/hello` and I get error `ImportError: No module named grpc.`

So then I installed grpc using `pip install grpc`. When I rebuild the artifact I now get error `Import grpc:No module named gevent.socket`.

Reading online indicated that the correct items to install were actually grpcio and grpcio-tools. So I tried `pip uninstall grpc` `pip install grpcio` and `pip install grpcio-tools`. Doing this and rebuilding the artifact gave me error `ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`. Trying to `pip install pkg_resources` gives error: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg_resources`

Having all `grpcio` `grpcio-tools` and `grpc` install gives the same error: `Import grpc:No module named gevent.socket`

This seems like it should be a very simple task. I simply want to use pyinstaller to build an artifact that has a dependency on grpc, how do I do this?

Comment: did you try `pip install gevent`? *No module named gevent.socket* suggests to me `gevent` is not installed?

Comment: yes I did try that. I then get error `Import grpc:No module named coros`. Then I try `pip install coros` and I get error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement coro`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am working on doing a PyInstaller/cx_freeze distributable of a python app using grpc.

Can you try adding `--hidden-import=pkg_resources` and see what happens?

This solved it for me

Comment: yes that did it - that in combination with making sure grpcio and grpcio-tools were installed. Thanks so much

Comment: Awesome! I was stuck on it for days :(

Answer (score 33):

I faced the same issue. I referred this document: [gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/quickstart/python.html)

As per the documentation, first upgrade your pip to version 9 or higher.

Then use the following commands:

```
$ python -m pip install grpcio
$ python -m pip install grpcio-tools
```

It worked for me!

Comment: `pip --version` gives `pip 9.0.1`. I ran `python -m pip install grpcio` and `python -m install grpcio-tools` and then running the built artifact gives `ImportError: No module named pkg_resources`

Comment: It seems the setuptools has some errors or has been deleted. Reinstalling setuptools might fix the issue. Here is the link: (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/0.9.8#installation-instructions)

Comment: You can run this command:

wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python

Comment: that link gave me a 404 so I used `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python`  followed by `python -m pip install grpcio` `python -m pip install grpcio-tools` `pyinstaller hello.py` `./dist/hello/hello` and that still gives `ImportError: No module named pkg_resources` doing python -m pip install pkg_resources` still gives No matching distribution found for pkg_resources`

Comment: This is the issue of setuptools. try reinstalling pip using get-pip.py. It will install setuptools if they are corrupted or deleted somehow. Here is how You can do this:
{ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py }
{ python get-pip.py }